# Unable to reach on my vagrant ubuntu machine webserver into windows host browser

Tags: vagrant, ubuntu-14.04, vagrantfile, vagrant-windows

I have setup vagrant on Windows 7. And setup a ubuntu 14.04 server on it.
I have installed apache web server on it .
But now i am unable to open that apache starting page in my browser .

Comment: please provide the Vagrantfile ? and how you try to access the site

Comment: @FrédéricHenri
 Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
  config.vm.hostname = "test-vm"

  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "172.128.33.1"
#  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 9000, host: 8080

  config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant_data"

   config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|

  #
  #   # Customize the amount of memory on the VM:
     vb.memory = "1524"
   end

Comment: @FrédéricHenri i am trying to access this by ip and port

Comment: I would try another IP, take 192.168.33.10 as an example

Comment: @FrédéricHenri If this exist in your network then what to do ?

Comment: Log into the vm and make sure apache is running and listening to port 9000. You can do this by issuing: `curl http://localhost:9000` at the command line (you may need to load curl).  If it is running, it will spit out the apache welcome page html.

Comment: @CurtEvans Issue related with vagrant 1.9 release . This version installed with Virtual box 5.1 and I unable to access on browser. 
Besides this i installed vagrant 1.8.5 with virtual box 5.0 and i am able to access on my host machine browser.